# Which GPUs offer the best support for linux?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, ati, steam

I have a HD 7870 graphics card on Ubuntu 15.04. The proprietary drivers have already phased it out for support, so I am debating getting a new graphics card.

The questions I am trying to ask is this; what proprietary drivers seem to be the most stable with Ubuntu, steam on linux, and in particular, mine craft?

Comment: refer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9553/how-do-i-choose-a-graphics-card-for-linux)

Comment: Thank you. That thread is a bit dated, but the opinions in there where very helpful.

Comment: NVIDIA has the best stable proprietary drivers once you actually get them set up and working, provided you also follow their method, which doesn't include Optimus and the like. However, it really depends on how much performance you're okay with gaining/losing.

Answer (score 3):

Nvidia graphics cards are cooler and quieter than similar capacity AMD graphics cards across the board, which is worth considering if you are using OptiFine HD mod in Minecraft. According to [Steam’s hardware survey](http://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey) as of August 2015 only 27.0 percent of Steam gamers have an AMD video card, compared to 52.2 percent for Nvidia.

Comment: I appreciate your thoughts

Answer (score 2):

The best experiences I have made with Nvidia. Of course with the proprietary drivers and currently with [this](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) PPA.